# Blocking builder with singleton

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton, synchronization

I am trying to implement a singleton builder that would be shared across
multiple builder threads for `Coordinate` objects.

Here is the simplified target class Coordinate with only two `Integer` fields.

```
public class Coordinate
{
    private final Integer x;
    private final Integer y;

    private Coordinate(CoordinateBuilder aBuilder)
    {
        x = aBuilder.x;
        y = aBuilder.y;
    }
}
```

`CoordinateBuilder` is a static inner class inside Coordinate.class and has two blocking methods for assigning fields `x` and `y` of the current `Coordinate` instance being built. When a thread calls one of them, the method blocks until the other field is assigned by another thread. Both threads should return together with the `Coordinate` that has just been created. If the current `Coordinate` object is being built, other threads should wait until the current target is created and returned to callers.

```
/* inside Coordinate.class */
public static class CoordinateBuilder
{
    private final static CoordinateBuilder builder = new CoordinateBuilder();

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private final Condition builderBusy; // cond. busy with building current instance
    private final Condition fieldWait; // cond. field

    private volatile Integer x;
    private volatile Integer y;

    private Coordinate current; // current instance being built

    private final static AtomicInteger assignedFieldNum = new AtomicInteger();
    private final static AtomicInteger readNum = new AtomicInteger();

    private CoordinateBuilder()
    {
        builderBusy = lock.newCondition();
        fieldWait = lock.newCondition();
    }

    public static CoordinateBuilder getBuilder()
    {
        return builder;
    }

    public Coordinate x(int aX) throws InterruptedException
    {
        lock.lock();

        try
        {
            while(x != null) // block other threads until current is built
            {
                builderBusy.await();
            }

            x = aX;

            if(assignedFieldNum.incrementAndGet() < 2) // wait until current.x and current.y are assigned
            {
                fieldWait.await();
            }
            else
            {
                current = new Coordinate(this);
                fieldWait.signalAll(); // instance built, wake up other builders
            }

            if(readNum.incrementAndGet() == 2) // reset state if all builders are about to return
            {
                x = null;
                y = null;
                assignedFieldNum.set(0);
                readNum.set(0);

                builderBusy.signalAll();
            }

            return current; 
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Coordinate y(int aY) throws InterruptedException
    {
        lock.lock();

        try
        {
            while(y != null) // block other threads until current is built
            {
                builderBusy.await();
            }

            y = aY;

            if(assignedFieldNum.incrementAndGet() < 2) // wait until current.x and current.y are assigned
            {
                fieldWait.await();
            }
            else
            {
                current = new Coordinate(this);
                fieldWait.signalAll(); // instance built, wake up other builders
            }

            if(readNum.incrementAndGet() == 2) // reset state if all builders are about to return
            {
                x = null;
                y = null;
                assignedFieldNum.set(0);
                readNum.set(0);

                builderBusy.signalAll();
            }

            return current; 
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

`CoordinateBuilder` can be used from a thread as:

```
CoordinateBuilder builder = Coordinate.CoordinateBuilder.getBuilder();

// from Thread 1
Coordinate coord = builder.x(i);

// from another Thread 2
Coordinate coord = builder.y(j);
```

Thread 1 and Thread 2 assign different fields of the `coord` object and block until the `coord` object is built. As a result, Threads 1 and 2 get the same `coord` object. Any other threads calling builder methods in the meantime will block until the current instance is built.

I tested it but I am still not sure if this implementation is thread-safe. Do you see any defect with this approach?

Comment: What is the purpose of `CoordinateBuilder` class? I cannot think of a situation where you would need something like this.

Comment: See my edit with some explanations for its purpose and how it is used.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is very fragile because of next reasons:

1. Threads which construct your object are depending on each other and blocks - this is bad - if something happens (interrupt/exception/bad scheduler event) and 2nd thread dies or not be able to complete - you will get deadlock. Even if this issue is avoidable with proper use of timeouts - this is still bad design to define these types of dependencies.
2. The API you have is just setting some value on the builder object and this is not intuitive that this simple call is actually (OMG!) blocking call dependent on some random other thread.

To design it in better way - I would suggest not to block on your `builder.x()` method but instead return your builder immediately (instead of the object itself) and have object as partially constructed at this stage.

And then to have method like:

Coordinate waitCompleted(long timeout)

Which will block till object you need will be fully assembled - providing timeout to stop waiting if it will not complete in some reasonable time and make sure thread calls it can progress. This will give you better control from caller side on what is happening with the object you are constructing. And both your threads will have code like this

```
CoordinateBuilder builder = Coordinate.CoordinateBuilder.getBuilder();

// from Thread 1
CoordinateBuilder partial = builder.x(i);
Coordinale = partial.waitCompleted(1000);


// from another Thread 2
CoordinateBuilder partial = builder.y(i);
Coordinale = partial.waitCompleted(1000);
```